# Errors including shared prebuilt libraries in petalinux

Tags: shared-libraries, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to simply include a couple of shared libraries to my petalinux project (Yocto based). Following the "Including Prebuilt Libraries" section  on pg 65 of the [petalinux guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf) I've got the next recipes to included both libraries (only I post one because the other is the same but only changing the name):

```
#
# This file is the libpiimager recipe.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple libpiimager application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://libirimager.so \
    "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "arch" 

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}/${libdir}
         install -m 0755 ${S}/libirimager.so ${D}/${libdir}
}

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
```

Building the image I've got the next errors:

```
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires ld-linux.so.3, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libgcc_s.so.1, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.5), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires ld-linux.so.3(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libc.so.6, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libm.so.6, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimager.so contained in package libpiimager requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libpiimager? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: Architecture did not match (ARM, expected AArch64) on /work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/libpiimager/1.0-r0/packages-split/libpiimager-dbg/usr/lib/.debug/libirimager.so [arch]
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: libpiimager-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/libpiimager/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.26170
ERROR: Task (/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-apps/libpiimager/libpiimager.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: Architecture did not match (ARM, expected AArch64) on /work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/libirimageprocessing/1.0-r0/packages-split/libirimageprocessing-dbg/usr/lib/.debug/libirimageprocessing.so [arch]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires ld-linux.so.3, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libstdc++.so.6, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libgcc_s.so.1, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires ld-linux.so.3(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.5), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libc.so.6, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libirimageprocessing.so contained in package libirimageprocessing requires libm.so.6, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libirimageprocessing? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/libirimageprocessing/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.26173
ERROR: Task (/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-apps/libirimageprocessing/libirimageprocessing.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: petalinux-user-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -y -c /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --installroot=/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/temp --nogpgcheck install shadow libpiimager libc6 webfwu pciutils libstdc++-dev i2c-tools mtd-utils packagegroup-core-boot watchdog-init busybox-httpd udev-extraconf packagegroup-petalinux-utils libc6-dev openssh-sftp-server canutils bootscript kernel-modules libstdc++6 packagegroup-petalinux-gstreamer run-postinsts base-passwd libomxil-xlnx libusb-1.0-0 libirimageprocessing libm3api2 bridge-utils tcf-agent packagegroup-petalinux-v4lutils hellopm packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear startup' returned 1:
Added oe-repo repo from /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Fri 10 Apr 2020 03:35:51 PM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15) needed by libpiimager-1.0-r0.aarch64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) needed by libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0.aarch64

ERROR: petalinux-user-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.26188
ERROR: Task (/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/project-spec/meta-plnx-generated/recipes-core/images/petalinux-user-image.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

I looked for the missing dependencies and they are all installed (last libraries versions), eg:

```
#sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.


#sudo apt-get install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu11).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Also I tried to include them in the recipe, e.g with:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libc6"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++6"
(...)
```

But still can't find the libraries and errors persists.

Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting those errors?

**EDIT:**

Well it looks like following to the below answer I'm doing some progress, I added the suggested to the recipe:

```
#
# This file is the libpiimager recipe.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple libpiimager application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://libirimager.so \
    "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "arch" 
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "file-rdeps"

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}/${libdir}
         install -m 0755 ${S}/libirimager.so ${D}/${libdir}
}

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
```

I'm having now less errors but still the next one:

```
ERROR: petalinux-user-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -y -c /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --installroot=/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/temp --nogpgcheck install libstdc++6 packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear base-passwd libomxil-xlnx packagegroup-petalinux-utils canutils packagegroup-petalinux-gstreamer hellopm libpiimager run-postinsts openssh-sftp-server libm3api2 libusb-1.0-0 bridge-utils packagegroup-petalinux-v4lutils libirimageprocessing tcf-agent webfwu pciutils libc6 libc6-dev shadow mtd-utils bootscript kernel-modules i2c-tools libstdc++-dev watchdog-init packagegroup-core-boot busybox-httpd udev-extraconf startup' returned 1:
Added oe-repo repo from /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sun 12 Apr 2020 04:40:52 PM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15) needed by libpiimager-1.0-r0.aarch64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) needed by libirimageprocessing-1.0-r0.aarch64

ERROR: petalinux-user-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynqmp-xilinx-linux/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.9499
ERROR: Task (/home/josee/hdl/dev/petalinux/sw_vlu/project-spec/meta-plnx-generated/recipes-core/images/petalinux-user-image.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Any ideas why I'm having these errors now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's warning about glibc support, try adding with `DEPENDS = " glib-2.0"`.

Comment: @CleitonBueno, thanks for the suggestion I tried that but unfortunately didn't work either, still same error, what I don't understand is why is complaining about those libraries if they are installed....

Comment: to give a complete answer, we would need to know your library's dependencies and have full access to the error log.

Comment: I can post the whole error log, but how can I list/show the library's dependencies?

Comment: If you have the source code, you can check the necessary libraries in the compilation by looking at the `LIBS` variable. If the lib is compiled, you can use the command `ldd` followed by the name of the library, it will return the dependent libraries. That would be it initially.

Comment: Please note that glibc is not provided by glib-2.0, that is a completely different project.
glibc should be provided by the cross-compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "file-rdeps"`

You're configuring the Yocto Project to ignore dependencies that should be in the recipe.

Example: If you have a shell script and use `/bin/bash` but did not include bash it in the dependencies it will launch this QA, with `INSIDE_SKIP_${PN} = "file-rdeps"`, solve it but you have to be sure of what you are doing .

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @Cleiton Bueno , thanks for you suggestion I added that to the recipe and I'm not getting any more that error, could you please explain what is doing this instruction? The problem now is that I'm having another errors, (I've updated my question with this)

Answer (score 0):

As many were asking for explications, I found this page pretty useful
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/current/singleindex.html#ref-classes-insane

Regarding the `file-rdeps` it says:

> - *file-rdeps*: Checks that file-level dependencies identified by the OpenEmbedded build system at packaging time are satisfied. For example, a shell script might start with the line #!/bin/bash. This line would translate to a file dependency on /bin/bash. Of the three package managers that the OpenEmbedded build system supports, only RPM directly handles file-level dependencies, resolving them automatically to packages providing the files. However, the lack of that functionality in the other two package managers does not mean the dependencies do not still need resolving. This QA check attempts to ensure that explicitly declared RDEPENDS exist to handle any file-level dependency detected in packaged files.

Comment: I just edited the answer. 
In reality I wanted my answer was a comment, but I do not have enough reputation points to add it (and all these minus do not help...)

Comment: Thank you for your willing to follow the rules. SO has a strict set of rules enforced by its community. About the comment problem, there is no shortcut that could allow you to post comments like they were answers. If you want to read the rationale behind this rule you can read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/why-do-we-need-50-reputation-to-make-comments