# Disable do_package_qa during bitbake

Tags: linux, build, yocto, bitbake

Is there any way to disable `do_package_qa` step during bitbake

Actually I have a precompiled binary which I want to copy to my rootfs. I have tried `install` as well as `cp` in the `do_install` section of my recipe.
In both the cases, I am getting QA issue which complains about `libQt5Qml.so` and `libQt5Quick.so` not being found in `RDEPENDS`.
I have tried `INSANE_SKIP_${PN}` , `RDEPENDS_${PN}` and `DEPENDS` to suppress the errors but I am not able to do so.
Is there any way with which I can compile my recipe ?

**Recipe**

```
DESCRIPTION = "..."
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "qtbase"

SRC_URI = "file://hello.c \
           file://basic \
           "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() { 
         ${CC} hello.c -o hello
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}/opt/mybin/
         install -m 0755 hello ${D}/opt/mybin/
         install -m 0755 basic ${D}/opt/mybin/
}

FILES_${PN} = "/opt/mybin/"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: my-binary-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/mybin/basic contained in package my-binary requires libQt5Qml.so.5(Qt_5), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_my-binary? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: my-binary-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/mybin/basic contained in package my-binary requires libQt5Quick.so.5(Qt_5), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_my-binary? [file-rdeps]
```

Comment: Showing your recipe as well as the error message would help tramendously.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk please check

Comment: `INSANE_SKIP_my-binary += "file-rdeps"`? However, the error is a valid one because if you silence it, your rootfs will actually not contain this non-versioned library of qt and your binary will fail to execute. You can either create a symlink to the versioned library of qt that is named the same way as the non-versioned library, or you can patch your binary with patchelf and make it use the versioned library instead.

Comment: `INSANE_SKIP_my-binary += "file-rdeps"` worked but there are some serious warnings, but I can ignore these warnings since I know that all the required libraries are available in my target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "file-rdeps"` might help to fix the error.

Reported issue is something similar to below link
[Errors including shared prebuilt libraries in petalinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144014/errors-including-shared-prebuilt-libraries-in-petalinux)

Comment: `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "file-rdeps"` worked with some serious warnings

Answer (score 1):

This should disable qa in recipe:

```
do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding

RDEPENDS_${PN} += " libQt5Qml.so.5(Qt_5) libQt5Quick.so.5(Qt_5)"

to your recipe it will solve the QA issue. Lets try.

Comment: I have tried it already
But getting `Nothing RPROVIDES libQt5Qml.so.5(Qt_5)` error

Comment: ok but your binary requires this library so you need to look if you have this libQt5Qml recipe somewhere on your yocto build system. It seems to be that you dont have it because if  the recipe exists it will automatically install the dependecy needed by this binary.

Comment: if no recipes exists you need to implement a new one in your custom layer. but google first :)

Comment: You need to add recipes providing the required `libs` to `RDEPENDS`, not the files. Also remember `RDEPENDS:${PN}` for newer Yocto releases.